# scala 2.13: type IndexedSeq takes type parameters

Tags: scala

I have the following snippet which works fine on Scala 2.12 but does not compile on Scala 2.13.

```
import scala.util.Random
object Hello {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val random    = new Random()
    random.shuffle[Int, IndexedSeq](2 to 100).toArray
  }
}
```

The error is:

```
trait IndexedSeq takes type parameters
```

I have no idea on how to fix it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add required type parameter:

```scala
random.shuffle[Int, IndexedSeq[Int]](2 to 100).toArray
```

Comment: Can I also ask why? What incompatible changes led to this behaviour?